# I can't insert values in database

Tags: php, html

Help I can't input values in database if my input has (') sign

if I go to chrome I can input it to my database but if I put (') sign it produce error

```
<form action="addsong.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Add A Song</h1>
    <div class="form-box">
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field title" name="title" placeholder="Title" required></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="verse1" placeholder="Verse 1" required></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="verse2" placeholder="Verse 2" ></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="verse3" placeholder="Verse 3" ></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="refrain" placeholder="Refrain" ></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="chorus" placeholder="Chorus" required></textarea>
        <textarea type="text" class="seach-field" name="bridge" placeholder="Bridge" ></textarea>
        <br /><br />
        <button type="submit" class="search-btn noEnterSubmit" name="add-song">Add</button>
        <button type="reset" onclick="window.location.href = 'index.php';" class="cancel left">Cancel</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

this is my addsong.php

*

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'copy_cat');

    $titles = $_POST['title'];
    $v1 = $_POST['verse1'];
    $v2 = $_POST['verse2'];
    $v3 = $_POST['verse3'];
    $refrain = $_POST['refrain'];
    $chorus = $_POST['chorus'];
    $bridge = $_POST['bridge'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO songs (title,verse1,verse2,verse3,refrain,chorus,bridge) VALUES ('$titless','$v1','$v2','$v3','$refrain','$chorus','$bridge')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Song Successfully Added";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Song Not Added";
        header('Location: error.php');

    }
```

Comment: you can use `addslashes()` in your php code. [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or if your using mysqli then  [mysql-escape-string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) . The problem is mostly like to be occured if you wrap sql query inside (') single quote or (") double quote and the values that you pass also contains the quote. you just need to escape it using addslashes or mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: Maybe `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? Your issue is with php and (my)sql, you've shown us html and not provided the error that was produced. Don't use `addslashes` use the method that's appropriate to the database you're corresponding with, addslashes does not account for charset like the database specific escaping functions do

Comment: @danish-khan-I you've linked a deprecated function. Do NOT use `mysql*` use `mysqli*`

Comment: just checked it here [https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: i use mysqli_real_escape_string() but it doest put ' in database

Comment: Show your php @Punisher, what you've provided isn't helpful for anyone trying to assist you

Comment: without looking into your code  @Punisher we can't help.

Comment: If you put a backslash( \ ) in front of the quotation it won't give you the error anymore.

Comment: @craft9841 in front of what quotation

Comment: In front of the (') sign in your input (what you are trying to send to the database). If everything else is fine then this should work.

Comment: Rather than escaping the string, do it properly and use prepared statements.  They provide other benefits rather than use something like a plaster to fix the current issue.

Comment: @craft9841 id there any possible way to save it to database

Comment: @NigelRen can you help[ me to fix this

Comment: Have a read of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1213708) from the first duplicate, it shows how to do a prepared statement.

Comment: ok i fix it ty guys have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax :**

`mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr ) : string`

`$link` is your database connection & `$escapestr`  is what you need to escape.

```
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'copy_cat');

    $titles = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title']); // this is what you were missing.
    $v1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['verse1']);
    $v2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['verse2']);
    $v3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['verse3']);
    $refrain = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['refrain']);
    $chorus = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['chorus']);
    $bridge = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['bridge']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO songs (title,verse1,verse2,verse3,refrain,chorus,bridge) VALUES ('$titless','$v1','$v2','$v3','$refrain','$chorus','$bridge')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Song Successfully Added";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Song Not Added";
        header('Location: error.php');

    }
```